# How to retrieve response data from a fetch post request?

Tags: fetch, fetch-api, svelte

I'm trying to display the data comes back from a server, I can see the data coming back from the server I'm hitting when I look at network tab in Chrome's developer window.

How can I get access to it in my code below?

The handleClick method is called when a button is clicked.

Thanks!

```
let data;
async function handleClick() {
        const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/parse"
         data  = await fetch(url, {
            mode: 'no-cors',
            method: "POST",
            headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
            body: new URLSearchParams({
                locale: "en_GB",
                text: "Test Message"
            })
        })
        .then(x => x.text())
        console.log(data)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Capture in the promise return section

.then(x => {
   // Catch the data through the propertiesName. 
   // Here properties means your post request's variable name which you are given.
   console.log(x.propertiesName);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,  this is what comes back and what I can see in the network tab. When I try to output anything I get undefined as the output. 

[{
    "body": "next week",
    "start": 10,
    ...
}]

Comment: `Get the value using x.body or x.start`

Comment: It comes back as null for body & undefined for start

Comment: Then first check the object named x. Then try with that. If not work, convert the object to json or stringify. Then access those properties in the same way.

Comment: When I print out x I can see body is null status is 0. This is confusing.